# How to add an element to an existing object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, typescript

I've got an object as per below:

```
{
id: 6,
url: 'https://google.com',
title: 'abc',
actions: 63,
status: 'active',
method: 'GET',
response_type: 'json' 
}
```

Now I want to push one more element in this object, the expected output is as per below:

```
{
id: 6,
url: 'https://google.com',
title: 'abc',
actions: 63,
status: 'active',
method: 'GET',
response_type: 'json',
new_ele: 'new_data'
}
```

Comment: No this is a simple object and by the way @mplungjan this is not duplicate.

Comment: yes it is a typescript thing like this -- {
id: 6,
url: 'https://google.com',
title: 'abc',
actions: 63,
status: 'active',
method: 'GET',
response_type: 'json' }

Comment: Yes I'm sure about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this by most simplistic way

```
var obj = {
id: 6,
url: 'https://google.com',
title: 'abc',
actions: 63,
status: 'active',
method: 'GET',
response_type: 'json' 
}
```

then use `obj.new_ele = 'new data'` or if your key is dynamic then you can use
`obj[new_ele] = 'new data'`.

Otheriwse if your environment supports ES6/later version of ES* syntax

use `Object.assign(obj, {new_ele: "new data"});`

Even with spread operator this becomes

```
let newObj = { ...obj, new_ele: 'new data' };
```